# Ubuntu 18.04 crashed. I am unable to understand what went wrong

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, crash, log

So my Ubuntu 18.04 crashed (froze). It seems like the sound service ended up crashing the entire system. Is it because I have set pulse audio's priority to `very high`? I changed pulse audio's daemon.conf and asound.conf for a higher quality output following standard guides available online.
The crash file's name is `_usr_bin_pulseeffects.1000.crash` that's present in `/var/crash`. Should I just uninstall pulse effects? ( I don't use it anymore)
If you need specific information straight from the .crash file itself, please tell me so. I'll try and give it to you. I am new to this and am unable to understand the .crash file to its full extent. These are the first few entries in the .crash file

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Date: Thu Sep  5 21:22:59 2019
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/pulseeffects
ExecutableTimestamp: 1566079691
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/pulseeffects --gapplication-service
ProcCwd: /home/abyssalcramps
ProcEnviron:
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 LANG=en_IN
```

There is a `ProcMaps` section after this, but I am unable to make sense of it. It seems like some sort of an execution order as there are cache accesses and application executions?
**NOTE: The crash log seemed to have been generated on September 5 for some reason. This is the only log available in `/var/crash/`**
If this .crash log cannot be the reason ubuntu crashed, where else can I find updated logs?

Comment: Oh. The log output was from the previous boot. Strange, ubuntu didn't crash at 21:22 though.

Comment: Done as you suggested! I have even added a note stating your point as I find the time difference between the crash log and the actual crash interesting.